Не работает SetActive(), окно не появляется
Реализовывал несложную паузу в игре.
Есть окно и кнопка, при нажатии на кнопку паузы должно появляться окно паузы
Скрипт приложу ниже, он находится на пустом объекте, который в свою очередь прикреплен к кнопке паузы.
Часть кода работает точно - пауза срабатывает, только вот окно не появляется. Ошибок консоль не выдает, просто не поваляется окно. Оно реализовано в Canvas картинкой
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Pause : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PauseScreen;

    public GameObject player;

    public void PauseOn()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().enabled = false;
        PauseScreen.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void PauseOff()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().enabled = true;
        PauseScreen.SetActive(false);
    }

}


Я не очень понимаю в юнити, но как у вас переменная public GameObject PauseScreen; инициализируется? Разве не нужно искать объект и присваивать в эту переменную? Или там как-то автоматически?

@CrazyElf я сам новичок, но вроде как чаще всего достаточно в Inspector подставить значения(

Я погуглил, а кто родители у PauseScreen, они то активны? Там пишут, что все родители должны быть активны, чтобы объект стал активным.

Если PausScreen это объект с Canvas, то меню и не появится.
Лучше всего создать пустой объект, добавить к нему компонент Canvas и уже внутри это объекта плодить нужные сущности, по типу Image, который отвечает за бэкграунд Меню и в неё уже дочерними сущностями добавлять кнопки и прочее что нужно.
К тому же вы у объекта Pause просите компонент PlayerMove.
Если вы хотите получить компонент PlayerMove у объекта player:
PlayerMove playerMove = player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>

Если вам нужен именно компонент PlayerMove, то лучше сразу опракинуть ссылку на него:
public class Pause : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PauseScreen;

    public PlayerMove player;

    public void PauseOn()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        player.enabled = false;
        PauseScreen.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void PauseOff()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        player.enabled = true;
        PauseScreen.SetActive(false);
    }
}


Почему бы вам просто не включать и выключать объект через Inspector, а вообще советую подучить основы Unity

Пожалуйста, отредактируйте ответ, добавьте больше информации, чтобы не приходилось догадываться о решении, а просто его прочитать. Также объясните, каким образом то что вы посоветовали отвечает на поставленный автором вопрос.
